# Calabash-Android loop through ListView

Tags: calabash-android

I've written a feature:

```
Feature: Open List item

  Scenario: As a valid user I can open list item
    When I press list item number 0
    Then I do something...
    Then I go back
```

What I would need is to open every item of ListView (not only 0th), so how could I specify a loop that would in the end iterate through whole ListView, or some specified maximum index - ie. for parameter value 5 it should execute this scenario for 0th, 1th, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th item.

So, two questions:
1) How to create a loop?
2) How to parametrize execution

Regards,
Milos

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you know the exact loop count, you can use `scenario outline` in cucumber.

```
Feature: Open List item

Scenario: As a valid user I can open list item
  When I press list item number <count>
  Then I do something...
  Then I go back

Examples:
| count |
| 1     |
| 2.    |
| ..    |
| n     |
```

More details about scenario outline: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines

> Or

**2.** You can get count using `query()` & iterate using `for each` loop in ruby

For getting count `query("view").count`

- Get the count.
- Store it in variable
- Loop it in step definition

Comment: Thanks, will try it out, and then accept the answer ;)